# Is the inverse of the differentiation chain rule true?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I know that if $f$ and $g$ are differentiable $g ◦ f$ is differentiable but is the other way around true? 
That is, if $g ◦ f$ is differentiable then $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable 
I suspect this isn't true, but couldn't come up with a counter-example

Comment: an even worse situation can be seen by the function $f=g= \mathbf{1}_\Bbb{Q}$ (i.e $f(x) =1$ if $x$ rational and $f(x)=0$ otherwise). Then, $f=g$ is nowhere continuous, so nowhere differentiable, yet the composition $(f\circ g)(x) = (f\circ f)(x)=1$ is the constant function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple counter-example is $$f,g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R,\ f(x)=\sqrt[3]x, \ g(x)=x^3.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! It so obvious now...

Comment: @PedroSilva You are welcome! :)